# highcharts can you tell how far in you are zoomed?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

we have a custom script to draw a box over a column in the bar chart (similar to what highcharts offers but encapsulates the axis and values as well). when a user zooms the chart, we need to know how much they have zoomed in order to resize our box accordingly. Any thoughts on how this might be achieved?

Comment: Could you show us what you've done so far?

Answer (score 1):

use the [afterSetExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events) event parameters (min and max) to get the current zoom status.